# which convergence test is better?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I need to check this one for absolute convergence  $$\sum^{\infty}_1 \frac {(-1)^n(n+4)}{(n^2+1)^{1/4}(2+\sqrt{n^2+3})}$$

But I am not sure which method to use, it fails with Root or Ratio tests.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{x^2 + 3}$ or $\sqrt{n^2 + 3}$?

Comment: Did you try Raabe's Test?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the general term is $n^{1-2/4-2/2}=n^{-1/2}$. Will diverge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+4}{(n^2+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}(2+\sqrt{n^2+3})}\div\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}}(n+4)}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(2+n\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n^2}}\right)}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{4}{n}}{(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{2}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n^2}}\right)}=1$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges,

the series of absolute values diverges by the Limit Comparison Test.